# Cloudformation AWS IAM Role with and without RoleName Parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

When creating a new IAM role resource using Cloudformation, `AWS::IAM::Role`.

There is an optional `RoleName` parameter, and I am not sure when if it is better practice to include the `RoleName` parameter or exclude it.

The following are the differences that are specified in the documentation

- If you don't specify a name, AWS CloudFormation generates a unique physical ID and uses that ID for the role name.
- If you specify a name, you must specify the CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM value to acknowledge your template's capabilities.
- Naming an IAM resource can cause an unrecoverable error if you reuse the same template in multiple Regions.

Are there any other functional differences betweeen using or excluding the `RoleName` parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will simply generate a name for you if you don't specify it (constructed from the stack and resource name with a random string at the end).

The only difference is re-usability. If you want to recreate the stack multiple times, it would be better to pass in this IAM role ARN as a parameter.

I'd recommend not naming, which will allow you the freedom to create the stack as many times as you want without the fear of breaking additional resources.

If you really must the recommendation from AWS is below:

> Naming an IAM resource can cause an **unrecoverable error** if you reuse the same template in multiple Regions. To prevent this, we recommend using Fn::Join and AWS::Region to create a Region-specific name, as in the following example: {"Fn::Join": ["", [{"Ref": "AWS::Region"}, {"Ref": "MyResourceName"}]]}.

Comment: Thanks, I am also looking for any differences during stack updates or changes? For some other resources I have encountered that Replacement is not possible during stack updates for a named resource.

Comment: Yes this can be possible for some resources during updates, because it keeps both resources going at the same time. Look at the parameter here for the update requiring a "Replacement": https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html. Other than RoleName all other Replacement attributes would not allow a named IAM role to be updated

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#cfn-iam-role-rolename) explains that it may be **dangerous** to name your roles:

> **Naming an IAM resource** can cause an **unrecoverable error** if you reuse the same template in multiple Regions. To prevent this, we recommend using Fn::Join and AWS::Region to create a Region-specific name, as in the following example: {"Fn::Join": ["", [{"Ref": "AWS::Region"}, {"Ref": "MyResourceName"}]]}.